# Extract metadata from excel file and inject it in to word document while uploading in alfresco 5.0.d

Tags: alfresco-share

My requirement is that, I want to Extract metadata from excel sheet and then i want to inject it in to word document while uploading or creating Document in alfresco.

Can any one help me with this.

if possible, please provide proper steps and code sample.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution for this is to create policies or using configuring rule in alfresco and firing java action in that.You can select any if them.
Below link will be help full in understanding above things.

Custom Action
http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html

Defining Rule
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/library-folder-rules-define.html

Policies
http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/behaviors/tutorial/tutorial.html

If you are going with policies you have to write code in that for extracting metadata..there are many java libraries there for extracting metadata.You can google it for the same.